# Limit a sorted number of rows joined

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have two tables, A and B, and a join table M. I want to, for each A.id, get the top 2 B.id's sorting on the value in table M, producing the results below. This is running on an Azure SQL database

```
Table A          Table M          Table B
+-----+   +-----+-----+-------+   +-----+
|  Id |   | AId | BId | Value |   |  Id |
+-----+   +-----+-----+-------+   +-----+
|   1 |   |   1 |   3 |     4 |   |   1 |
|   2 |   |   1 |   2 |     3 |   |   2 |
|   3 |   |   3 |   2 |     3 |   |   3 |
|   4 |   |   3 |   5 |     6 |   |   4 |
+-----+   |   3 |   3 |     4 |   |   5 |
          |   4 |   1 |     2 |   +-----+
          |   4 |   2 |     1 |
          |   4 |   4 |     3 |
          +-----+-----+-------+

                 Result
          +-----+-----+-------+
          | AId | BId | Value |
          +-----+-----+-------+
          |   1 |   3 |     4 |
          |   1 |   2 |     3 |
          |   3 |   5 |     6 |
          |   3 |   3 |     4 |
          |   4 |   1 |     2 |
          |   4 |   4 |     3 |
          +-----+-----+-------+
```

I know that I can select all the M.AId rows where they equal 1, sort it, and limit by 2, but I need to do this for every row in Table A. I've made an attempt to use group by, but I wasn't sure how to sort and limit it. I've also tried to search for resources associated with this issue but I couldn't find any resources.

(I also wasn't sure how to word the title for this issue)

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: It's an Azure SQL database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use [**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
SELECT
    AId, BId, Value
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AId ORDER BY Value DESC)
    FROM M
) t
WHERE Rn <= 2
```

Comment: Could you explain what's happening with 'Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AId ORDER BY Value DESC)', that's the part I'm struggling to understand.

Comment: @JoeC I added a link in my answer. Hopefully, that'll help.

Comment: So PARTITION BY is conceptually breaking down M into individual tables for each AId, then you're doing operations on them like any result set.